# Connect to Mongo DB on MongoLab without Authorization?

Tags: mongodb, mlab

**My Question:**

Is there any way to connect to Mongo DB (hosted on MongoLab) without username and password ?

**My Case:**

I have created a free MongoLab account (https://mongolab.com) and also create new database -> collection -> document in it.

When I connect to Mongo DB (on Mongo Lab) without username and password, I was able to connect, but when I try to retrieve any data it gives me "unauthorized db:testing lock type:-1 client:...." error.

So I have created a DB User in MongLab as well and provide username and password at the time of connection. After that I am able to connect and retrieve data from Mongo DB.

Comment: If that would work everybody could access your data. You'd like that?

Comment: Thanks @johannes for response. I think this should be optional for user whether user wants to apply authentication or not .. as in my case it doesn't matter as am doing some testing/analysis

Comment: I am doing some benchmarking with and without authentication. I have done it on local db and now want to do it on mongo lab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoLab's multi-tenant database plans are on shared servers. We cannot give you the choice to forgo authentication. Even if you were ok with others seeing you data, the other tenants on the server you share would still not want you to see *their* data.

We have dedicated server plans where you have your own server. On those we could turn off authentication for you. Email us at support@mongolab.com.

As for your benchmarks - auth will not slow things down. The drivers do not authentication on each request, just each connection. If you use the driver properly it should all work well.

-will (MongoLab)